# CC1120 and STM32

Tags: msp430

I am currently using `TrxEB` based on `msp430` and an `RF module` based on `CC1120`.

I'd like to use the `STM32` microprocessor instead of my current `msp430`.

Is is possible to change the `MCU` in `Smart Rf` to a `CC1120 SPI connection`.
If not, why is it not possible?

Answer (score 0):

well, inspecting the smartFr datasheet shows that it requires that the CCxxxx chip you are using is connected to a supported cpu. I doubt that a stm32 from STmicro is one of them. thus it will be difficult to use smartRf in that configuration.

Comment: thank you for your reply,
I found an example in a forum which has a base SmartRF use a micro STM32 using a CC3000 RF. Here is what "The CC1120 is a transceiver that communicates with a MCU through SPI. The development kit for the CC1120 (CC1120DK) has a evaluation board (trxEB) which uses a MSP430F5438A. All code examples that we release for the CC1120 is written for operation with this MSP430, but there is no limitation on what kind of MCU you can combine with the CC1120."I like to understand or be the problem??????

Comment: ok but as  I understand the smartRF system, it seems to be a Pc software which communicate with an eval board  which is connected with a CCxxxx chip.

Comment: ok but as  I understand the smartRF system, it seems to be a Pc software which communicate with an eval board  which is connected with a CCxxxx chip. But in order to be able to communicate with the Ccxxxx chip, a special firmware should be flashed into the microcontroller.  if you have nothing into the microcontroller or another  unrelated software, it won't work because the microcontroller won't recognize the commands sent by the Pc. I haven't  tried, but that's what suggests the datasheet.

Comment: Yes SmartRF is a software installed on PC contacted TrxEB evaluation board (it is based on a microcontroller MSP430F5438). My goal is to replace it by another microprocessor is provided STM32 let the CC1120 RF communication module installed on the evaluation board. So communication is between STM32 and CC1120.possible or not? What are the constraints???

Comment: Yes, the communication between the STM32 and the CC1120 will be possible. The STM32 (if you choose a model that has an SPI) has the required hardware to connect to the CC1120. Just make sure the IO voltage of the CC1120 is the same than the STM32. What I am not sure to understand is if you want to still by able to use the SmartFR software. I think it won't be the case if you replace the MSP430 by a STM32.

Comment: ok,SmartRF™ Studio is a Windows application that can be used to evaluate and configure Low Power RF-ICs from Texas Instruments.Since the module CC1120 is still connected on the evaluation board MCU will be changed only other application Smart Rf help designers of RF systems to easily evaluate the RF-IC at an early stage of the design process so I do not think it will depend on TrxEB MCU install????? Either it depends MSP430F5438A installed???

Comment: Ok I see. SmartRF runs on Windows. But PCs do not have any SPI port to connect to a CC1120. To achieve that, the PC is connected to an eval board that MUST include a microcontroller that is supported by smartRF. Then, the microcontroller forwards the packets received from to PC to the CC2011 using SPI connection. It does so because SmartRF will probably program the microcontroller on the eval board with a special firmware that know how to do this. It you use another eval board, such as one with a STM32, smartRF does not have the corresponding firmware for it. And this will not work.